# React website only rendering component after changing detail in app.tsx and saving but disappears upon webpage reload

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rest

I have never ran into a problem quite like this before but I am attempting to load Home from App where Home fetches data from an API and maps the data calling a component with props to create a bunch of components using the data.  This works but only after the conditions described above.  I believe it to be a rendering issue but haven't been able to pinpoint it yet and wanted to see if I was missing something stupid.  I am attempting to use the component below inside of Home on top of App.  I'm also really sorry for posting images. I know to do the inline code but I couldn't get it to work for the life of me.  Parts of the code kept being left in the text body so apologies its images.

[image: App.tsx]

[image: Home.tsx part 1]
[image: Home.tsx part 2]

[image: MangaClickable.tsx(Component)]

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue many times, and most of the times it is just because of the missing dependency array in the `useEffect(() => {}, [dependencies])`.

In both your components, `Home` and `MangaClickable`, you can see a yellow squiggly line on the dependency array. Try hovering over it and add the suggested dependencies.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not fix the issue but I am glad you pointed that out.  I ended up moving the logic from inside getNewUpdatedManga and tempMangaArray inside the useEffect and the warnings subsided.  Thank you